# Javascript validate Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello my validate form in Javascript have errors
I only want to put characters not value type integer.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["fomr"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "" || x= "{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}") {
        alert("O novo valor tem de ser preenchido!");
        return false;
    }
}   
</script>
```

Error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function validateform()**

Comment: You might calling function  `validateform()` but your function name is `validateForm()`. Please check spelling of function

Comment: In JavaScript, `validateform()` ≠ `validateForm()`. JavaScript is **CaSe SeNsItIvE**.

Change it to **`validateForm()`**.

Comment: This is not the problem

Comment: Then you have to provide the entire code @PauloRodrigues

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the last x:

```
x.search(/^[A-Z ]+$/i)
```

And then it will look like this:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["fomr"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "" || x.search(/^[A-Z ]+$/i)) {
        alert("O novo valor tem de ser preenchido!");
        return false;
    }
}   
</script>
```